# Incorrect boolean checking for Prime

Tags: python

Why does the following code return True when it should return False. Trying to test if number is prime.

The intent of the code is to loop the this range(2,n) and if any number i divides n (remainder is 0) return False. The code returns True (incorrect) for 25 but False (correct) for 20. When the loop reaches 5 then 25%5 is 0 so it should return False. Where did I go wrong. There are other ways to check if number is prime but I want to know why this way does not work for 25 but does for 20.

```
def isPrime(n):
    """ 
    """
    for i in range(2,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def main():
    print isPrime(25) #Should return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is another implementation without the return statements that get so the area of the code that I would like to better understand.

```
for i in range(2,n+1):
    if n%i == 0:
        print 'for i =',i,'n%i =',n%i,'Therefore',n,'is not a prime'
        print 'Should break out of loop here and return False'
    else:
        print 'for i =',i,'n%i =',n%i
```

Here is sample output.

```
for i = 2 n%i = 0 Therefore 10 is not a prime
Should break out of loop here and return False
for i = 3 n%i = 1
for i = 4 n%i = 2
for i = 5 n%i = 0 Therefore 10 is not a prime
Should break out of loop here and return False
for i = 6 n%i = 4
for i = 7 n%i = 3
for i = 8 n%i = 2
for i = 9 n%i = 1
```

So, shouldn't have broken out where i is 2 or when i is 5 when n is 10? Why doesn't it?

Comment: Think about the logic. Maybe print what's happening line by line or use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/ to visualise it. You've made a very obvious mistake; *"when the loop reaches 5"* never happens.

Comment: @martinbshp the `return ` statement will break the loop and returns with that value , So in your question when `n=25` for the first loop `n%i==0` that means `25%2==0` is wrong. So it will move to else part and will `return True` and break from the loop. Thats why you are getting `True` when n=25. For your second case when `n=10`, in the first loop that means `10%2==0` is true and `return False` there also it will break loop and returns. So problem is in your loop and you can try answer I given or give any count number and check with that and return prime or not .

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are checking with each number in that range and at the same time you are returning true or false, that's a bad idea. you have to return false if all the numbers in that range not matching with your condition. Instead of that in your coding you are checking for each element.

```
def isPrime(n):
    """ 
    """
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    else:
            return True
print isPrime(25)
```

So if you write the `else` with `for loop` it will first execute for all the elements in range if nothing is matching it will it will go to the else part rather than checking `if:..Else:..` for each element in that range.

Comment: It's no *just* indentation, that's changing the logic. It would be helpful to explain how and why this changes the output. Also: the indentation in the else block is weird and you're using *three* spaces?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe here the else is applicable to all the values of i in range, rather that each if condition, its properly working if it inside that function , you can check here : https://repl.it/repls/IvoryAshamedAnaconda

Comment: Yes, *I* know that, but then I didn't have to ask the question. The point is there's no explanation here *for the OP*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok I will add an explanation in my answer for unerstanding purpose of OP

Comment: Thanks for the response Vikas. I edited the code above to better addressed the gap in understanding why it does not work.

Comment: @martinbshp add a `break` in your `if`, it will exit from the loop